# Prevent or disable automatic image resize in a div with css (using bootstrap)

Tags: css, image, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to show the original size of the image. Often that's bigger than the width of the div that's containing it.

In modern browsers, it gets automatically resized to fit the parent div. Even when I use `overflow: auto` the image still gets resized.

So how can I prevent the image from getting resized when the outer div has a set width?

Thank you!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Bootstrap have maximum width set to 100% on images. Change it:

```
img {
    max-width: none;
}
```

Comment: It would be better to create a class that overrides bootstrap, rather than modifying Bootstrap's core layout. Example: `img.oversize: {max-width: none}`

Comment: Note that this is also true of Zurb Foundation (as of 6 anyway).

Answer (score 3):

I used this one  `img {min-width:100%}`

Comment: You might want to add an explanation